# ¿Como actualizar un campo especifico de una tabla sin estar relacionada con otra por foránea?

Tags: javascript, mysql, mvc, método

tengo un pequeño problema con este codigo y tal vez alguien me pueda ayudar.
pasa que tengo tres tablas, prestamo, elemento, inventario. las tablas prestamo y elemento estan relacionadas, pero la de inventario no, el caso es que a la hora de yo hacer un prestamo se tiene que disminuir la cantidad en la tala elemento del "elemento" que estoy prestando, bueno hasta aqui funciona a la perfeccion. la pregunta es, ¿como hago para al mismo tiempo tambien me disminuya esa cantidad en el inventario teniendo en cuenta que inventario NO esta ralacionada con ninguna tabla?

tengo este metodo hasta el momento...

```
public boolean AgregarPrestamo(int id_persona, int id_elemento, int id_curso, int cantidad_elem_pres, String fecha_hora_prestamo, String estado_inicial) {
    String consulta = "insert into prestamo values ("+null+","+id_persona+","+id_elemento+","+id_curso+","+null+","+cantidad_elem_pres+",'"+fecha_hora_prestamo+"',"+null+",'"+estado_inicial+"','"+null+"');";
    String consulta1 = "update inventario set ejemplares=ejemplares-"+cantidad_elem_pres+";";
    String consulta2 ="UPDATE elemento SET ejemplares=ejemplares-"+cantidad_elem_pres+" where id_elemento="+id_elemento;
    System.out.println(consulta);
    System.out.println(consulta1);
    System.out.println(consulta2);
    if (con.insertarDatos3(consulta,consulta1,consulta2)) {
        con.desconectar();
        return true;
    } else {
        con.desconectar();
        return false;
    }
}
```

el problema es que me si me actualiza la cantidad en la tabla inventario, pero no del elemento en especifico, si no que actualiza la cantidad de todos los elementos del inventario...

agradezco su ayuda, un saludo

Comment: Que guardas en la tabla elemento?

Comment: guardo libros, brou

Comment: Explica que guardas en cada una de las tablas. Creo que en inventario guardas la informacion de existencia de los libros, en elemento guardas los libros y en la otra guardas los prestamos.?

Comment: si, es correcto, la tabla prestamo tiene un campo que se llama (cantidad_elem_pres) que es el numero de libros por prestar, ese numero tiene que disminuir en la tabla elemento en el campo (ejemplares) el caso es que esto ya pude hacerlo ya que estas tablas estan relacionadas, pero inventario no esta relacionado a ninguna de estas dos tablas, y a la hora de disminuir en su campo que tambien se llama (ejemplares), me disminuye la cantidad que preste pero en todos los elementos que hay en la tabla y no del especifico que preste.

Comment: No estaría mal que añadieras la estructura de estas tres tablas, porque estamos intentando ayudarte un poco a ciegas. Aunque por lo que he leido, puedo aventurarme a decir que tu relación de tablas podría mejorarse, aunque no podría decirte como hasta que añadas la estructura.

Answer (score 1):

Tu estructura podría quedar de la siguiente manera:

```
Inventario:                Elementos:          Prestamos

id                         id                  id

cantidad_disponible        id_inventario       id_elemento

estatus                    libro               fecha_prestamo
```

Cuando procesas un préstamo, el libro lo seleccionas de la tabla elementos, haces todo el proceso de verificación de existencia, disponibilidad etc. Si el libro esta disponible vas a restar 1 a cantidad_disponible de la tabla inventario, eso lo haces obteniendo id_inventario del libro que has escogido y haces el UPDATE en la tabla inventario donde el id sea igual al id_inventario que envías.

Me parece que eso es lo que necesitas.

Answer (score 0):

Estaría bueno ver cuales son los campos con los que cuentan las tablas.
En principio, lo que veo es que tu `update` de la tabla inventario es general para todos los ejemplares, ya que no tiene un `where`:

```
String consulta1 = "update inventario set ejemplares=ejemplares-"+cantidad_elem_pres+";";
```

te tendría que quedar  asi:

```
String consulta1 = "update inventario set ejemplares=ejemplares-"+cantidad_elem_pres+" where id_elemento=[id_elemento];";
```

Soy medio nuevo en esto pero creo que ahí está el problema.

Comment: Es justo lo que pregunto, es que esa tabla no está relacionada, si lo estuviera, la consulta quedaría como usted dice, pero no se puede hacer esa consulta si la tabla no está relacionada y si la relaciono con elemento o con préstamo, no funciona un agregar... En fin ya valí